# Change border radius for <lightning-input>

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lwc-dom

Is there any way to change style for < lightning-input> in LWC (not Aura)?

all I want is change the border radius and color.
I could have used slds input for styling then I have to write all kind of custom validation myself.

```
inputField.setCustomValidity("some custom validation error");
inputField.reportValidity();
```

This simply works in lightning-input

Comment: Try [styling hook](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/#site-main-content) `--sds-c-input-radius-border` [Input Styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#Styling-Hooks-Overview)

Answer (score 2):

You cloud use the Styling Hooks Overview. Add following in your CSS file:

```
lightning-input{
--slds-c-input-radius-border: 3rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also override the style using something like this

```
style="border:solid red; border-radius: 2%;"
```

Comment: When you inspect lightning-input you'll see there are parent elements to the input tag. Styling only gets applied to outer element